# how to extract last day date of the month from this string 'opimus_rise_issue_command_201912.txt'

Tags: sql, oracle

i want last date of the corresponding month and year  from the string

```
'opimus_rise_issue_command_201912.txt'
```

expected output--

```
20191231
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few nested functions might help.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'opimus_rise_issue_command_201912.txt' from dual)
  3  select to_char(last_day(to_date(regexp_substr(col, '\d+'), 'yyyymm')), 'yyyymmdd') result
  4  from test
  5  /

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------
20191231

SQL>
```

Comment: the final result is a string or date datatype. i need  date datatype final result

Comment: This is a string, formatted as your example shows. Just remove the outermost TO_CHAR and it'll be a DATE.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
 select LAST_DAY(to_date(regexp_replace('opimus_rise_issue_command_201912.txt', '[^0-9]', '') ||'01','yyyymmdd')) from dual;
```

31/12/2019